# call a function to another function

Tags: laravel

How can i call function `search` to `print` funcion, i have button to print in a view blade so i want when i click to print the page

```
     public function searchstockview(Request $request) {


     $search=DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT products.id, (select ifnull(sum(loadings.qty),0) from 
      loadings 
       where 
            loadings.pid=products.id and 
                   DATE(loadings.Outdate) <= STR_TO_DATE('$date1','%d,%m,%Y')) as 
        total_loadings_till_date," 
        from products ));
     return view('report.searchstockview',compact('stocksummary','startdate','enddate'));

       }
```

i want to call above function and print, when click button on my blade

```
          public function print(){

        $pdf = 
     PDF::loadView('report.stocksummaryprint',compact('stocksummary','startdate','enddate'))- 
     >searchstockview($request);

     return $pdf->download('stock Summary.pdf'); 

       }
```

Than you In advance

Comment: please share your blade template with the print button

Comment: ` <h3 class="box-title">Stock Summary Report:: From{{$startdate}} To {{$enddate}}</h3>
          <a href="{{url('report/stocksummaryprint')}}" class="btn btn-info btn-xs pull-right"><i class="fa fa-print"></i>  Print</a>`